# Executing callbacks in sequential order without using Promises

Tags: javascript, callback, functional-programming

I am trying to execute following array (avoid callbackHell) of functions in a sequential order implementing function `runCallbacksInSequence` (I need to implement my own function to understand how callbacks work and avoid using Async.js). Here is what I have so far. I do not quite understand how callbacks work that is why I am doing this exercise. If you have any ideas let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it.

```js
function first(cb) {
  console.log('first()');
  cb();
}
function second(cb) {
  console.log('second()');
  cb();
}
function third(cb) {
  console.log('third()');
  cb();
}
function last() {
  console.log('last()');
}

let fns = [first, second, third, last];

function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
  return fns.reduceRight((acc, f) => f(acc), cb);
}

runCallbacksInSequence(fns, second);
```

**callbackHell**

```
// first(function() {
//   third(function() {
//     second(function() {
//       last();
//     });
//   });
// });
```

**UPD**

```
    const cache = {};

    function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
      fns.reduce(
        function(r, f) {
          return function(k) {
            return r(function() {
              if (cache[f]) {
                return;
                // f(function(e, x) {
                //   e ? cb(e) : k(x);
                // });
              } else {
                cache[f] = f;
                return f(function(e, x) {
                  return e ? cb(e) : k(x);
                });
              }
            });
          };
        },
        function(k) {
          return k();
        }
      )(function(r) {
        return cb(null, r);
      });
    }
```

Comment: FYI async.js is a library that handles this quite well if you don't want to use promises.

Comment: @VaughanHilts I need to implement my own function to understand how callbacks work

Comment: Sorry, I was implying you could look at the source to see how this is _usually done_ Happy to help -- but I guess I'm asking: what can I _really_ do for you? I guess I can fix the bug in your above approach but it's not necessairly the best one.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @VaughanHilts I did look at the source and to tell you the truth it was a bit too much for me to understand it . I really appreciate your effort to help anyway!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Promise based sequence converting into Callback based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422248/promise-based-sequence-converting-into-callback-based)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the `.reduce` callback be a *higher-order* function, which, when called, calls the next function in the chain with the callback. At the end, you'll have a function chain that will start by calling the first function, then the second, etc:

```js
function first(cb) {
  console.log('first()');
  cb();
}
function second(cb) {
  console.log('second()');
  cb();
}
function third(cb) {
  console.log('third()');
  cb();
}
function last() {
  console.log('last()');
}

let fns = [first, second, third, last];

function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
  const chainedFns = fns.reduceRight((acc, f) => () => f(acc), cb);
  return chainedFns();
}

runCallbacksInSequence(fns);
```

If you wanted the `runCallbacksInSequence` to accept *another* callback to run at the end of all of them, then:

```js
function first(cb) {
  console.log('first()');
  cb();
}
function second(cb) {
  console.log('second()');
  cb();
}
function third(cb) {
  console.log('third()');
  cb();
}
function last(cb) {
  console.log('last()');
  cb();
}

let fns = [first, second, third, last];

function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
  const chainedFns = fns.reduceRight((acc, f) => () => f(acc), cb);
  return chainedFns();
}

runCallbacksInSequence(fns, () => console.log('outer call'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fns.reduceRight((acc, f) => f(acc), cb)
```

runs

```
[first, second, third, last].reduceRight((acc, f) => f(acc), second)
```

which turns into

```
((acc, f) => f(acc))(
    ((acc, f) => f(acc))(
        ((acc, f) => f(acc))(
             ((acc, f) => f(acc))(
                 second,
                 last
             ),
             third
        ),
        second
    ),
    first
)
```

(because that's what `reduceRight` does).

The first thing to run is the innermost call,

```
 ((acc, f) => f(acc))(
     second,
     last
 )
```

This becomes

```
last(second)
```

which (by the definition of `last`) is equivalent to

```
(function () { console.log('last()'); })(second)
```

This expression ignores `second`, writes `last()` to the console, and returns `undefined`.

This leaves our expression as

```
((acc, f) => f(acc))(
    ((acc, f) => f(acc))(
        ((acc, f) => f(acc))(
             undefined,
             third
        ),
        second
    ),
    first
)
```

The next innermost call is

```
((acc, f) => f(acc))(
     undefined,
     third
)
```

which turns into

```
third(undefined)
```

By the definition of `third` this is equivalent to

```
(function (cb) {
    console.log('third()');
    cb();
})(undefined)
```

which in turn executes

```
console.log('third()');
undefined();
```

This writes `third()` to the console, then throws an exception because `undefined` is not a function.

Comment: thank you for details! I was not sure how to debug it

Answer (score 1):

Your callbacks never pass arguments, `cb()`. In a real program, you will likely want to get a result back. The callback is meant to receive some sort of message - ie, what are you calling back *to say*? In this program, we'll send some messages out and make sure all of them get passed to the final callback -

```js
function first(cb) {
  console.log('first()')
  cb(1) // return some result
}

function second(cb) {
  console.log('second()')
  cb(2) // return some result
}

function third(cb) {
  console.log('third()')
  cb(3) // return some result
}

function last(cb) {
  console.log('last()')
  cb('last') // return some result
}

function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
  fns.reduce
    ( (r, f) => k => r(acc => f(x => k([ ...acc, x ])))
    , k => k([])
    )
    (cb)
}

const fns =
  [ first, second, third, last ]

runCallbacksInSequence(fns, results => {
  console.log("-- DONE --")
  console.log(...results)
})
```

The output is -

```
first()
second()
third()
last()
-- DONE --
1 2 3 'last'
```

---

For an extra dose of functional programming -

The reducer above is based on a fundamental data structure called *Continuation*. If we extract it, we can see what `runCallbacksInSequence` is doing more clearly -

```
function append (a = [], x = null) {
  return a.concat([ x ])     // basic append operation
}

function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
  Cont.run
    ( fns.reduce             // in the context of Cont ...
        ( Cont.lift2(append) // reduce using append
        , Cont.of([])        // init with empty array
        )
    , cb
    )
}
```

Here's `Cont` -

```
const Cont =
  { of: x =>
      k => k (x)
  , lift2: f => (mx, my) =>
      k => mx (x => my (y => k (f (x, y))))
  , run: (c, k) =>
      c (k)
  }
```

Expand the snippet below to see the result in your own browser -

```js
function first(cb) {
  console.log('first()')
  cb(1) // return some result
}

function second(cb) {
  console.log('second()')
  cb(2) // return some result
}

function third(cb) {
  console.log('third()')
  cb(3) // return some result
}

function last(cb) {
  console.log('last()')
  cb('last') // return some result
}

const Cont =
  { of: x =>
      k => k (x)
  , lift2: f => (mx, my) =>
      k => mx (x => my (y => k (f (x, y))))
  , run: (c, k) =>
      c (k)
  }

function append (a = [], x = null) {
  return a.concat([ x ])
}

function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
  Cont.run
    ( fns.reduce
        ( Cont.lift2(append)
        , Cont.of([])
        )
    , cb
    )
}

const fns =
  [ first, second, third, last ]

runCallbacksInSequence(fns, results => {
  console.log("-- DONE --")
  console.log(...results)
})
```

---

Using `reduce` is not the only way to express this kind of program. Programming is all about inventing your own convenience. What if we could have an intuitive, magical function like `$` below? We could start with some value and then just chain as many steps necessary -

```
$ ([])
  (andAppend(first))
  (andAppend(second))
  (andAppend(second))
  (andAppend(third))
  (andAppend(third))
  (andAppend(third))
  (andAppend(last))
  (x => console.log ("done", x))

// first()
// second()
// second()
// third() 
// third()
// third()
// last()
// "done" [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, "last" ]
```

Any simple function can go in the sequence -

```
function progress(p) {
  console.log("progress:", p)
  return p
}

$ ([])
  (andAppend(first))
  (andAppend(second))
  (progress)
  (andAppend(third))
  (andAppend(last))
  (x => console.log ("done", x))

// first()
// second()
// progress: [ 1, 2 ]
// third()
// last()
// "done" [ 1, 2, 3, "last" ]
```

This appears to be a very intuitive way to work with our asynchronous functions. We just have to implement `$` now. How hard could it be?

```
const $ = x =>
  k => $(Promise.resolve(x).then(k))
```

And now we implement `andAppend` -

```
function andAppend(f) {
  return acc =>
    new Promise(r =>
      f(x => r([ ...acc, x ]))
    )
}
```

Expand the snippet below to see it working your browser -

```js
function first(cb) {
  console.log('first()')
  cb(1)
}

function second(cb) {
  console.log('second()')
  cb(2)
}

function third(cb) {
  console.log('third()')
  cb(3)
}

function last(cb) {
  console.log('last()')
  cb('last')
}

function andAppend(f) {
  return acc =>
    new Promise(r =>
      f(x => r([ ...acc, x ]))
    )
}

function progress(p) {
  console.log("progress:", p)
  return p
}

const $ = x =>
  k => $(Promise.resolve(x).then(k))

$ ([])
  (andAppend(first))
  (andAppend(second))
  (progress)
  (andAppend(third))
  (andAppend(last))
  (x => console.log ("done", x))
```

Comment: really detailed answer. Thank you for the effort! Now I have to digest it ;)

Comment: I've changed your the code to fit the requirement of the task I am trying to accomplish. The only problem I have is how to implement the `cache` to avoid duplication of the `callbacks`.  Let me know if you have anyideas. You can see the updates in the original question.

Comment: Happy to help, John. What do you mean by _"avoid duplication of the callbacks"_? In the update, you have `if (cache[f]) return;` What is supposed to happen with a "cached" callback? It looks like you removed the ability to callback with a value too. What is the expected output? At this point, you should probably start pasting real code instead of over-simplifying your problem. It make us guess and/or make assumptions and potentially wastes a lot of time.

Comment: When I mentioned about the duplication I ment that the same `callback` is not executed more than one time. As an example let say we have the following array `const fns = [first, second, second];` the expected output should be `first()
second() two`

Comment: The reason I tried to implement the `cache` is to register the `callback` and when we see the same one next time we do not execute it and go to the next one. This is where is my main problem. I am not sure how to implement this logic. This is the part that you mentioned `if (cache[f]) return;`. We suppose to return something  or maybe not to return? I am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: The other part that you mentioned in regards to the removed the ability to callback with the value. You are absolutly right. I had to adjust the code to pass only the value of the last callback. The expected output of the example I have in the original question is `first()
second()
third()
last()
lastCall`