# Passing the result of the callback down the chain in sequential order to the outer callback

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass the result of each callback down the chain in a sequential order and print it in the outer call. If you have any ideas let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it.

```
function first(cb) {
  console.log('first()');
  cb(null, 'one');
}
function second(cb) {
  console.log('second()');
  cb(null, 'two');
}
function third(cb) {
  console.log('third()');
  cb(null, 'three');
}
function last(cb) {
  console.log('last()');
  cb(null, 'lastCall');
}

let fns = [first, second, third, last];

function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
  const chainedFns = fns.reduceRight((acc, f) => () => f(acc), cb);
  return chainedFns();
}

runCallbacksInSequence(fns, function(err, results) {
  if (err) console.log('error');
  console.log('outer call results: ' + results); // the results should equal to 'one','two', 'three', 'lastCall'
});
```

Comment: if promisifying is an option, that might be simpler

Comment: what is the actual output ?

Comment: @AyushGupta I am trying to do it with callbacks just for educational purpose

Comment: @axelaxel `first()
second()
third()
last()
outer call results: lastCall`

Comment: @axelaxel it only prints the result of the last callback

Comment: Well you never use the results that are passed to your callbacks, you're not even specifying parameters for them? Start with that.

Comment: You might want to start without `reduceRight` and look for what you'd like a non-generic call of your four functions to do. Write the calls explicitly, with nested callbacks, and get your results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing callbacks in sequential order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471930/executing-callbacks-in-sequential-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this was nowhere to save the callback result in each time.
So I try like this.

```js
function first(cb) {
    console.log('first()');
    cb(null, 'one');
  }
  function second(cb) {
    console.log('second()');
    cb(null, 'two');
  }
  function third(cb) {
    console.log('third()');
    cb(null, 'three');
  }
  function last(cb) {
    console.log('last()');
    cb(null, 'lastCall');
  }
  
  let fns = [first, second, third, last];

  function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
    let a = [];
    fns.map(fn => fn((err, result) => a.push(result)))
    cb(null, a);
  }
  
  runCallbacksInSequence(fns, function(err, results) {
    if (err) console.log('error');
    console.log('outer call results: ' + results); // the results should equal to 'one','two', 'three', 'lastCall'
  });
```