# Error handling executing callbacks in sequential order

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute following array (avoid callbackHell) of functions in a sequential order implementing function `runCallbacksInSequence` (I need to implement my own function to understand how callbacks work and avoid using Async.js). I do not quite understand how callbacks work that is why I am doing this exercise. Here is what I have so far. Overall the function `runCallbacksInSequence` works well but I am not sure if I am handling the errors in a right way.  If you have any ideas let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it.

```
    function first(cb) {
      console.log('first()');
      if (!cb) return cb(new Error('Invalid object'), null);
      cb(null, 'one');
    }
    function second(cb) {
      console.log('second()');
      if (!cb) return cb(new Error('Invalid object'), null);
      cb(null, 'two');
    }
    function third(cb) {
      console.log('third()');
      if (!cb) return cb(new Error('Invalid object'), null);
      cb(null, 'three');
    }
    function last(cb) {
      console.log('last()');
      if (!cb) return cb(new Error('Invalid object'), null);
      cb(null, 'lastCall');
    }

    let fns = [first, second, third, last];

    function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
      const chainedFns = fns.reduceRight((acc, f) => () => f(acc), cb);
      return chainedFns();
    }

    runCallbacksInSequence(fns, function(err, results) {
      if (err) return console.log('error: ' + err.message);
      console.log('outer call results: ' + results); 
    });
```

Comment: `if (!cb) return cb(...)` is going to cause you all sorts of issues. How can you call `cb` if you've just established it as _falsy_?

Comment: @Phil good point . it proves again I do not understand how it works. How would you handle it?

Comment: By using [`async / await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) ([promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)) and throwing errors when they occur

Comment: @Phil I have to avoid using promises and async/await.

Comment: Mind if I ask why? You're really just looking at callback hell here. It might help if you explain what the expected result / output is

Comment: @Phil the function `runCallbacksInSequenceit` should execute the functions from the array in a sequential  order and if there is an error the outer callback should be called with the error message. if there is no error the outer callback should be called with the result of the last function that was executed.

Comment: @JohnJohn, but you are not doing anything in your functions. What should be the the criteria for your functions to throw an error?

Comment: @mgarcia just posted the solution that handles the errors and the async

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing callbacks in sequential order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471930/executing-callbacks-in-sequential-order)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

The following solution will handle the errors and the async behavior

```
    function first(cb) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('first()');
        cb(null, 'one');
      }, 0);
    }
    function second(cb) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('second()');
        cb(null, 'two');
      }, 100);
    }
    function third(cb) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('third()');
        cb(null, 'three');
      }, 0);
    }
    function last(cb) {
      console.log('last()');
      cb(null, 'lastCall');
      // cb(new Error('Invalid object'), null);
    }

    function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
      fns.reduce(
        (r, f) => k => r(acc => f((e, x) => (e ? cb(e) : k([...acc, x])))),
        k => k([])
      )(r => cb(null, r));
    }

    const fns = [first, second, third, last];

    runCallbacksInSequence(fns, function(err, results) {
      if (err) return console.log('error: ' + err.message);
      console.log(...results);
    });
```