# Implementing sequential callback execution

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute following array (avoid callbackHell) of functions(sync/async), in a sequential order, implementing function `runCallbacksInSequence` (I need to implement my own function to understand how callbacks work and avoid using Async.js).

I do not quite understand how callbacks work that is why I am doing this exercise. Here is what I have so far. The function `runCallbacksInSequence` works well but I am having hard time to implement `callback (null, result)` signature. At the moment it follows `callback (result)` signature.

If you have any ideas let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it.
- **no promises and async/await**

```js
function first(cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('first()');
    cb('one');
    // cb(null, 'one');
  }, 0);
}

function second(cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('second()');
    cb('two');
    // cb(null, 'two');
  }, 100);
}

function third(cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('third()');
    cb('three');
    // cb(null, 'three');
  }, 0);
}

function last(cb) {
  console.log('last()');
  cb('lastCall');
  // cb(null, 'lastCall');
}

function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
  fns.reduce((r, f) => k => r(acc => f(x => k([...acc, x]))), k => k([]))(cb);
}

const fns = [first, second, third, last];

runCallbacksInSequence(fns, results => {
  console.log('-- DONE --');
  console.log(...results);
});
```

Comment: How about using ES6 syntax with async/await functionality? It does exactly what you need.

Comment: @Maksim no promises and async/await in this case

Comment: If you can't use Promises, I suggest using [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). Or use Babel (which will convert Promises to generators)

Comment: You can keep passing a callback to next function.

Comment: @Seblor the OP is trying to learn the pattern by implementing it. It is an exercise to learn not production code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing callbacks in sequential order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471930/executing-callbacks-in-sequential-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `runCallbacksInSequence` you first of all have to move the `x` to the second position, also for consistency the final callback should be called with its first argument being `null`:

```
 function runCallbacksInSequence(fns, cb) {
   //                                    v  v                                  vvvvvvvv
   fns.reduce((r, f) => k => r(acc => f((e, x) => k([...acc, x]))), k => k([]))(r => cb(null, r));
 }
```

If you want the first callback with an error (having the first argument set) to directly terminate the chain, you can extend your chain a bit:

```
 //                                              vvvvvv
 fns.reduce((r, f) => k => r(acc => f((e, x) => e ? cb(e) : k([...acc, x]))), k => k([]))(r => cb(null, r));
```

Comment: does it make a difference if we use `err` instead of `null`

Comment: Yes, that ends the chain

Comment: so I have to handle the errors cause when I call it with `cb(err, null)` it gives me an error `ReferenceError: err is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

To answer *I do not quite understand how callbacks work*
A callback is a function that is to be executed after another function has finished executing. For example.

```
function run(cb){
  console.log("run")
  cb("okay it is running");
}
```

A simple function that logs stuff. How do you run it?

```
run()
```

But you want to receive the callback. To know that above `cb()` everything was done. You do this.

```
run((arg) => {
  console.log(arg) //logs "okay it is running"
});
```

What you actually got is a "call", "back" from the function you ran, while running it.